# How to remove default margin in react bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jsx, react-bootstrap

I am creating a home page in react using bootstrap but everything is coming automatically using different margins in both sides on the container. How to make the 'section' container so that it will cover both sides in any screen size.
P.S. I have tried putting marginBotton:-10rem but as soon as screen size changes it distorts everything,

```
class Home extends Component {


render() {
    return (
      <div>
         <div className="container">
                <Navbar style={{marginBottom: "0"}} inverse className="fixed-top collapseOnSelect nav-bar" bg='dark' expand='sm'>
                <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
                <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                <a href="/alogin" class="navbar-brand text-white">Tailoring Store</a>
                <Nav className="ms-auto navbar-dark py-3">
                
                    
        <NavLink className= "d-inline p-2 bg-dark text-white" style={{textDecoration:'none'}} to="/alogin">Login as Admin</NavLink>
                    <NavLink className= "d-inline p-2 bg-dark text-white" style={{textDecoration:'none'}} to="/tlogin">Login as Tailor</NavLink>
                    <NavLink className= "d-inline p-2 bg-dark text-white" style={{textDecoration:'none'}} to="/clogin">Login as Customer</NavLink>
                </Nav>
                </Navbar.Collapse>
            </Navbar>
            </div>
        <div
          className="bg-dark text-light p-5 text-center text-sm-start"
          style={{ marginTop: "4.5rem", marginLeft:"0", padding:"0"  }}
          inverse
        >
          <div className="container">
            <div className="d-sm-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
              <div>
                <h1>
                  Welcome to the
                  <span className="text-warning">Tailoring Store</span>
                </h1>
                <p className="lead my-5">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum
                  in dolores impedit ipsam voluptatibus reprehenderit suscipit.
                  Unde quos voluptas explicabo?
                </p>
              </div>
              <img
                className="img-fluid w-30 d-none d-sm-block"
                src="https://seeklogo.com/images/T/tailor-store-logo-22F77490D5-seeklogo.com.png"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

[image: this is the ss for reference]

Answer (score 1):

Simply add fluid, which allows you to available spaces

`<Container fluid> ... </Container>`